# java two dimensional array add method

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, addition

this is my first question on Stack! I'm having a small problem populating a 2d arraylist with arraylists, using the add method. After adding my first arraylist to the 2d arraylist, and attempting to repopulate the SAME 1d arraylist, adding this 1d arraylist again to the 2d arraylist seems to alter the first element of the 2d arraylist I added...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> oneDArray = new ArrayList<String>();

oneDArray.add("a");

twoDArray.add(oneDArray);

System.out.println("First element in twoDArray: " + twoDArray.get(0)); //prints [a]

twoDArray.add(oneDArray);

oneDArray.clear();

oneDArray.add("b");

twoDArray.add(oneDArray);

System.out.println("First element in twoDArray:" + twoDArray.get(0)); //prints [b]
```

In practice, oneDArray is actually a local variable inside an iterator, hence why I am attempting to re-use it. I add elements to oneDArray, and when a check returns true, I add oneDArray to twoDArray, empty oneDArray, then continue this process, creating a list of lists.

Would this be to do with twoDArray.get(0) actually holding a pointer to oneDArray, and not it's actual value? If so, how might I work around this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT: solution to above issue**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> oneDArray = new ArrayList<String>();

oneDArray.add("a");

twoDArray.add(new ArrayList<String>()); // Create new arraylist inside twoDArray

twoDArray.get(0).add(oneDArray.get(0)); // Populate new arraylist rather than hold reference to oneDArray

oneDArray.clear();

oneDArray.add("b");

twoDArray.add(new ArrayList<String>());

twoDArray.get(1).add(oneDArray.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are not creating oneDArray inside the loop and merely clearing it will be overwritting on each iteration, that is why the elements are lost. This is indeed because you have the same reference to the same inner arraylist. You should do `ArrayList<String> innerToBeAdded = new ArrayList<>()` inside your loop conditional to create a new arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You say " I add oneDArray to twoDArray, empty oneDArray, then continue this process, creating a list of lists", but what you are really doing is adding the same array multiple times to the twoDArray. Because the exact same array is added multiple times to the twoDArray, when you clear() it, it clears *all* the values, and when you add a value to oneDArray it will appear in *all* the places in twoDArray.

Instead of clearing the array, what you should do is create a new instance array:  `oneDArray = new ArrayList<String>();` This will create a different array as each member of twoDArray

Comment: ah I understand. I created an extra for loop to execute once the condition was met - to add all oneDArray.get(i)'s to twoDArray.get(0), clear oneDArray and proceed to populate twoDArray this way. This seems to work successfully, but is it a suitable work around?

Comment: That does not sound right. You need to somewhere have `new ArrayList<String>()` for each array you add to twoDArray

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention... I would use twoDArray.add(new ArrayList<String>()) each time I am to populate twoDArray!

Comment: Then the question you have asked, and the code you have shown, is nothing like what you say you now have. Please update your question to have the code you are actually running.